# How to use GameCenter inside a React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, game-center

Im building a react native game app and I want to use game center to log the player in. To be more specific, all I want is the unique id that game center provides for the player. I plan on using firebase to store the information but I want the log in experience to be quick and easy. I do not know objective C so im hoping somebody has figured out how to do this already.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links I found, hope this helps!

https://developer.apple.com/game-center/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html

Comment: These links do not mention React Native anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I created a package for it this weekend . https://github.com/garrettmac/react-native-game-center

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but for what you want to do the easiest thing would be to use Firebase Auth and enable GameCenter login.

Once enabled, you will need to configure your user's login with the following [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage).

[image]